# Bounty late acceptance (award dodge)

Tags: discussion, bounties, accepted-answer

Can someone please explain if I just don't understand the bounty rules properly or the following is a dodge to avoid awarding bounty points? Oh and I should state that while this did happen to me, I don't **think** the op was doing it maliciously in my case. I am just wondering if it could be used that way.

1. A bounty of 100 rep was offered on a question.
2. I answered the question.
3. Op let bounty expire (I get half the rep from community)
4. Op returns a week later and accepts answer

At best I only get half of a bounty award (my case 100 doesn't mean much but what if it was 500). At worst I get nothing if there weren't enough answer votes.

I think the checks/balances for the bounty award system are currently sufficient (they should lean towards protecting the op from not getting a good/sufficient answer, and they do). If the same op accepts the answer late though, shouldn't the full bounty be awarded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bounties can be awarded to any answer for any reason, and do not necessarily correlate with the acceptance of a particular answer.

It looks like your answer wasn't accepted just a week later, but **1 and a half months later**. Either the OP had been AWOL for that long, or people were nagging him about his accept rate (I see a short burst of accepts in his activity) and he just went and accepted some previous answers where he could, or something else had happened.

Even if awarding bounties correlated with accepting answers, having a bounty be awarded in full if an answer was accepted late could easily be gamed by, say, accepting an answer immediately after a bounty has been automatically awarded.

Since the system already [does its best to ensure that any bounties put out don't go to waste](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), I think there is less of a chance that an asker would maliciously withhold a full bounty from an answerer than that an asker would game bounties in other ways, e.g. awarding them to sock puppets instead. I agree that the difference between 250 and 500 is pretty great, though...

Comment: Thanks for the info. I figured the OP was fixing his low acceptance rate which was why I didn't want to base the question on my particular experience, just have it be a general question. I definitely agree with you that most [reputable] users won't abuse the "half price bounty" loophole.